# In Springboot, can we configure a LogstashSocketAppender from application.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, slf4j

In my Springboot app, I want to use a logback's [LogstashSocketAppender](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder/blob/master/src/main/java/net/logstash/logback/appender/LogstashSocketAppender.java) so I can push my logs to a Logstash TCP server. 
For this, I want to put all the configuration inside my application.yml and get rid of the logback.xml configurarion. Is it possible?

I am aware that [RollingFileAppender](https://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html) can be configured on application.yml but not sure for a TCP SocketAppender.

Comment: As I know, for rolling file appender, you have to write config in xml file.

Comment: Are you able to do it ??